# Want to do Recursion, load category in undercategory

Tags: c#, recursion, treeview

At the moment I have this Code (Deepth = 2 Categories)

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Kategorie kategorie in mainViewModel.Kategorien)
    {
        if (kategorie.Oberkategorie == null)
        {
            TreeViewItem newChild = new TreeViewItem();
            newChild.Header = kategorie.Bezeichnung;
            treeView.Items.Add(newChild);

            foreach (Kategorie unterkategorie in mainViewModel.Kategorien)
            {
                if (unterkategorie.Oberkategorie != null)
                {
                    if (unterkategorie.Oberkategorie.Id == kategorie.Id)
                    {
                        TreeViewItem subItem = new TreeViewItem();
                        subItem.Header = unterkategorie.Bezeichnung;
                        newChild.Items.Add(subItem);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to make a recursive method, where I could have n Categories in undercategories and so on, I tried things like:

```
foreach (Kategorie kategorie in mainViewModel.Kategorien)
{
       FillKategorienTreeView(kategorie);
}
```

and then:

```
private void FillKategorienTreeView(Kategorie kategorie)
        {
            //if (kategorie.Oberkategorie == null)
            //{
            //    TreeViewItem newChild = new TreeViewItem();
            //    newChild.Header = kategorie.Bezeichnung;
            //    treeView.Items.Add(newChild);
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //    if (kategorie.Oberkategorie.Id == kategorie.Id)
            //    {
            //        TreeViewItem subItem = new TreeViewItem();
            //        subItem.Header = kategorie.Bezeichnung;
            //        newChild.Items.Add(subItem);
            //    }
            //}
        }
```

and other similiar things and it didn't work, I'm not so friendly with recursion but in this case it's indispensable..

There's a Treeview, which has a TopLevel (Maincategory) and can have n under/subcategories.

Hope u can help me

EDIT: The Category Object:

```
    [DataMember]
    public int Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set
        {
            if (_id != value)
            {
                if (ChangeTracker.ChangeTrackingEnabled && ChangeTracker.State != ObjectState.Added)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("The property 'Id' is part of the object's key and cannot be changed. Changes to key properties can only be made when the object is not being tracked or is in the Added state.");
                }
                _id = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Id");
            }
        }
    }
    private int _id;

    [DataMember]
    public string Bezeichnung
    {
        get { return _bezeichnung; }
        set
        {
            if (_bezeichnung != value)
            {
                _bezeichnung = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Bezeichnung");
            }
        }
    }
    private string _bezeichnung;

    #endregion
    #region Navigation Properties

    [DataMember]
    public TrackableCollection<Artikel> Artikel
    {
        get
        {
            if (_artikel == null)
            {
                _artikel = new TrackableCollection<Artikel>();
                _artikel.CollectionChanged += FixupArtikel;
            }
            return _artikel;
        }
        set
        {
            if (!ReferenceEquals(_artikel, value))
            {
                if (ChangeTracker.ChangeTrackingEnabled)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot set the FixupChangeTrackingCollection when ChangeTracking is enabled");
                }
                if (_artikel != null)
                {
                    _artikel.CollectionChanged -= FixupArtikel;
                }
                _artikel = value;
                if (_artikel != null)
                {
                    _artikel.CollectionChanged += FixupArtikel;
                }
                OnNavigationPropertyChanged("Artikel");
            }
        }
    }
    private TrackableCollection<Artikel> _artikel;

    [DataMember]
    public TrackableCollection<Kategorie> Unterkategorie
    {
        get
        {
            if (_unterkategorie == null)
            {
                _unterkategorie = new TrackableCollection<Kategorie>();
                _unterkategorie.CollectionChanged += FixupUnterkategorie;
            }
            return _unterkategorie;
        }
        set
        {
            if (!ReferenceEquals(_unterkategorie, value))
            {
                if (ChangeTracker.ChangeTrackingEnabled)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot set the FixupChangeTrackingCollection when ChangeTracking is enabled");
                }
                if (_unterkategorie != null)
                {
                    _unterkategorie.CollectionChanged -= FixupUnterkategorie;
                }
                _unterkategorie = value;
                if (_unterkategorie != null)
                {
                    _unterkategorie.CollectionChanged += FixupUnterkategorie;
                }
                OnNavigationPropertyChanged("Unterkategorie");
            }
        }
    }
    private TrackableCollection<Kategorie> _unterkategorie;

    [DataMember]
    public Kategorie Oberkategorie
    {
        get { return _oberkategorie; }
        set
        {
            if (!ReferenceEquals(_oberkategorie, value))
            {
                var previousValue = _oberkategorie;
                _oberkategorie = value;
                FixupOberkategorie(previousValue);
                OnNavigationPropertyChanged("Oberkategorie");
            }
        }
    }
    private Kategorie _oberkategorie;
```

Comment: Can you show us the Kategorie object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will only work if each category has a list of children or sub categories in the object.  If not then you will have to build the list of children for each item.

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Kategorie kategorie in mainViewModel.Kategorien)
    {
        LoadTreeviewItem(kategorie, null);
    }
}

private void LoadTreeviewItem(Kategorie kategorie, TreeViewItem parentItem)
{
   //Stop condition
   if(kategorie == null) return;

   TreeViewItem newChild = new TreeViewItem();
   newChild.Header = kategorie.Bezeichnung;
   treeView.Items.Add(newChild);

   if(parentItem != null) // Add to parent if it is not null
   {
      parentItem.Items.Add(newChild);
   }
   else //Otherwise this is the top level so add to treeview
   {
      treeView.Items.Add(newChild);
   }

   foreach (Kategorie subkategorie in kategorie.Unterkategorie)
   {
       LoadTreeviewItem(subkategorie, parentItem);
   }
}
```